# Is it possible to create a Set as a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

On the coding side of things, a Set data structure has three distinctive characteristics:

1. Every item in the Set is unique
2. The elements have no ordering
3. Adding an element that already exists in the Set is essentially a no-op

2 is easy enough in a SQL table, and 1 can be achieved by putting a unique constraint on the column(s) in question, but I wonder about #3.  If you try to insert a value which is already there into a table constrained by a unique index, it will error out.  Is there any way to design a table in SQL Server to ignore that error and just silently do nothing?  Or does it have to be handled client-side, catching that error and ignoring it?

Comment: use a trigger to rollback the insert on duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

You understand how to handle (1) and (2).

For (3), you just need to implement an `instead of` trigger.  If the value is already in the table, then the trigger would do nothing (not attempt an insert).

You can read about `instead of` triggers in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx).